# SDL event.window.windowID vs GetWindowID()

Tags: c++, events, input, sdl, sdl-2

What is the difference between the output of `event.window.windowID` and `SDL_GetWindowID()`?

Why is it that `std::cout << m_SDLEvent.window.windowID << std::endl;`
 outputs **1819558491** in  console while `std::cout << SDL_GetWindowID(m_SDLWindow) << std::endl;` outputs **1** ?

How would I achieve getting the right ID of my `SDL_Window*` in the method below?

```
void InputManager::Update()
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&m_SDLEvent);

                switch (m_SDLEvent.type)
                {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    std::cout << m_SDLEvent.window.windowID << std::endl;
                    SDL_HideWindow(SDL_GetWindowFromID(m_SDLEvent.window.windowID));
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so HolyBlackCat's answer brought me to the right direction.

Instead of using `SDL_QUIT` (which is the quit event for the entire app, not one window) I should've checked for `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE` which is an `SDL_WINDOWEVENT` which can be received by `m_SDLEvent.window.event` instead of `m_SDLEvent.type`

So the code now looks like this:

```
void InputManager::Update()
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&m_SDLEvent);

        if (m_SDLEvent.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT)
        {
            switch (m_SDLEvent.window.event)
            {
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE:
                std::cout << m_SDLEvent.window.windowID << std::endl;
                SDL_HideWindow(SDL_GetWindowFromID(m_SDLEvent.window.windowID));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now `std::cout << m_SDLEvent.window.windowID << std::endl;` outputs the correct ID.

Comment: It's not completely correct. First, you have to check that `m_SDLEvent == SDL_WINDOWEVENT`. Only then you can switch on `m_SDLEvent.window.event`. Otherwise the approach is good.

Comment: thank you very much. Edited it, and it works just fine

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was sleepy while writing the comment. ._. The correct way is `while (SDL_PollEvent(&m_SDLEvent)) {if (m_SDLEvent.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {switch(...){...}}}`.

Comment: oh yeah. corrected it... since in my case I already implemented the loop elsewhere I dont need to do to a `while()` loop anymore

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing garbage window ID because you access an inactive union field. That's undefined behavior.

You can only access `m_SDLEvent.window` if `m_SDLEvent.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT`.

But if `m_SDLEvent.type == SDL_QUIT`, you have to use `m_SDLEvent.quit` structure, which has no field for window id (because SDL_QUIT is not specific to a window, but means that the entire application should be closed).

Comment: is SDL_QUIT the only event that is called when clicking the "X" ? I want to get the SDL_Window on which I clicked "X" and hide it. therefore I need the ID of that window. how would i get that ID?